# Why does Rxjs publishReplay(1).refCount() not replay?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Why does publishReplay(1).refCount() not replay the last value for late subscribers?

```js
a = new Rx.Subject(); 
b = a.publishReplay(1).refCount(); 

a.subscribe(function(x){console.log('timely subscriber:',x)});
a.next(1); 
b.subscribe(function(x){console.log('late subscriber:',x)});
```

```html
<script src="http://reactivex.io/rxjs/user/script/0-Rx.js"></script>
```

Expected output:

```
timely subscribe: 1
late subscriber: 1
```

Actual output

```
timely subscriber: 1
```

Answer (score 9):

This happens because at the time you call `a.next(1)` the `publishReplay(1)` hasn't subscribed to its source Observable (Subject `a` in this case) and therefore the internal `ReplaySubject` won't receive the value `1`.

In RxJS 5 the actual subscription between operators happens when you subscribe at the end of the chain which is `b.subscribe(...)` in this example. See:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/multicast.ts#L63
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L96

Until you call `subscribe()` the operators are chained thanks to `lift()` method that just takes an instance of operator and assigns it to the new Observable. The `operator.call()` method as you can see in the two links above is called later when subscribing. See:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L67

Comment: But if `a` was itself defined as a ReplaySubject you would see that value:-)

Answer (score 1):

Your first subscriber subscribes to `a`, since `refCount` first activates the stream when there is at least 1 subscriber (of which there is none, because not `b` but `a` is subscribed), it is not active until your last loc.

```js
a = new Rx.Subject(); 
b = a.publishReplay(1).refCount(); 

b.subscribe(function(x){console.log('timely subscriber:',x)});
a.next(1); 
b.subscribe(function(x){console.log('late subscriber:',x)});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```